# My sumif sum wrong value

Tags: excel

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-UxDz2ZmU7GZumCZ-H2SxWeuczgsAUdAamIp46iXZ_4/edit#gid=0

Please See my sheet from the link

In column J,L,N,P,R Value is wrong

But the problem is 000 and 00 is not the same text but it sum as it same how do i fix this solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying that `001` should have the same value as `1` when you sum it?

Comment: make example with correct output

Comment: He is saying that `001` `SUMIF()` value should be 10, etc. in column F but instead it is being treated as a `1`.

Comment: Don't force a change in cell alignment if you are going to take the lazy route and supply a link to a google-sheet instead of posting sample data. If you had left numbers defaulted to right-alignment and text to left-alignment it would have been obvious to anyone at first glance that you were mashing together data types and not using custom number formatting to achieve your leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you have `001` and want it to NOT be summed, put an apostrophe in front of it `'001`.

Comment: its not finish yet

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your values in Column A to text. Either prepend an apostrophe to value in the column (e.g. 01 = '01, 1 = '1), which will tell excel that it is to treat the values as strings, or alternatively, you can try changing the data type of the column to text using the dropdown list in the ribbon.

If you go with the first solution, a quick way is to use this formula and drag it down the column:

="'"&A1

Then copy and paste the results as values over your original column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How about i change criteria about E1 need value = 3 characters how do i write it

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure I understand. Can you rephrase?